# Why does an HTML link appear blue in Outlook 2010?

Tags: html

I want to fix this link appearing in the color blue, when it should be white. It happens in outlook 2010.

```
<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;">
    You are subscribed with email address
    <font style="color: rgb(255,255,255);"><%user.Email%> </font>
    <a href="<%unsubscribe_link_text%>"
        style="color: rgb(174, 215, 51) ! important;">
        <font style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">Click here</font>
    </a> to unsubscribe.
</span>
```

Can anyone see whats wrong with that and help me? :)

Comment: Ah I was wondering if there was something like that I don use Stack that often so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this 
`style="color: rgb(174, 215, 51) ! important;`
to 
`style="color: #ffffff";`

Comment: It works when you work with a link on regular words, but **if you use a domain name or an e-mail address as readable text** (so not just as a link behind a word), **it will printed in blue** nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;">
You are subscribed with email address
<font style="color: rgb(255,255,255);"><%user.Email%> </font>
<a href="<%unsubscribe_link_text%>"
    style="color: #ffffff ! important;">
    <span style="color: #ffffff;">Click here</span>
</a> to unsubscribe.
</span>
```

notice the span inside the a

Answer (score 2):

I've always set my colours in the style sheet against the a tag as follows and should work fine in Outlook.

```
a:link {
color: #666666;
}

a:visited {
color: #666666;
}

a:active {
color: #666666;
```

Comment: Good to know! I'm told strictly to use inline styles for email here.

Comment: Other web clients ignore embedded stylesheets so this will not work universally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hex colors instead of RGB.

Master guide: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thanks - seems that Outlook doesn't like RGB in some places :)